# Destroy the clones by walking into them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I found a good re-spawner for my game and I respawn 50 spheres. I want them to disappear when I walk into them but they do nothing.

Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class BoxDestroy : MonoBehaviour 
 {
      void OntriggerEnter(Collider collider)
      {
          if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
          {
             Destroy(gameObject);
          }
      }
  }
```

Here is my re-spawner:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject objectToSpawn;
    public int numberOfEnemies;
    private float spawnRadius = 5;
    private Vector3 spawnPosition;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start ()
    {
        SpawnObject (); 
    }

    void Update () 
    {

    }

    void SpawnObject() 
    {
        for (int i= 0; i < numberOfEnemies; i++)  
        { 
             spawnPosition = transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * spawnRadius; 
             Instantiate(objectToSpawn, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Ive tried everything it feels like` what does this mean..? have you tried debugging the code to see what's going on ..?

Answer (score 1):

`OntriggerEnter` should be `OnTriggerEnter`! Case sensitive :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually tag your player-gameobject with a "player" tag?

Did you mark the colliders as triggers? OnTriggerEnter vs OnCollisionEnter

Do you have a rigidbody component on your player object?